# Overload C/C++ preprocessor macro on structure of its argument

Tags: c++, c, overloading, c-preprocessor

I would like to write a preprocessor macro that does one thing if it's argument is a parenthesized tuple of tokens, like this:

```
MY_MACRO((x, y))
```

and something else if it's just a single token, like this:

```
MY_MACRO(x)
```

Is that possible?

How about distinguishing between the number of space-separated tokens, i.e. between `MY_MACRO(x)` and `MY_MACRO(x y)`?

Note that I am not trying to overload based on the number of arguments - it's a unary macro in all cases.

**EDIT**: I am willing to use variadic macros if they help

Comment: This is impossible in C/C++. You should define two different macros. Write more detailed what do you need (code example).

Comment: For the first question:  with or without variadic macro support?  For the second question:  no.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632300/looping-through-macro-varargs-values has some ideas you can use

Comment: @James Yes, I am willing to use variadic macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for your first question, the following macros might meet your purpose:

```
#define CONCAT_( x, y ) x ## y
#define CONCAT( x, y ) CONCAT_( x, y )
#define IS_SINGLE_1(...) 0
#define IGNORE(...)
#define IS_SINGLE_2_0           0 IGNORE(
#define IS_SINGLE_2_IS_SINGLE_1 1 IGNORE(
#define IS_SINGLE( x ) CONCAT( IS_SINGLE_2_, IS_SINGLE_1 x ) )
IS_SINGLE((x, y)) // 0
IS_SINGLE(x)      // 1
```

Macro `IS_SINGLE` is expanded to 1 if the argument is single token,
otherwise, 0.

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I assume the other one (distinguishing between number of space-separated tokens) is impossible as James said...

Comment: For space-separated it's impossible. For comma-separated, there is a solution for any bounded limit on the number of arguments.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Thanks! As you mentioned, as for space separated arguments,
unless arguments are strictly restricted(for example only `x`, `y` and `z` are
allowed), I think it is generally very difficult(impossible?)...
If `m4` is allowed, probably it is the way to go :-)

Comment: This is the first time I hear of `m4`... it looks interesting. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Using boost.preprocessor

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define SEQ (w)(x)(y)(z)

#define MACRO(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_CAT(elem, data)

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, _, SEQ) // expands to w_ x_ y_ z_
```

It's not exactly the same as even a single argument case requires parenthesis. But It does allow a variable number of parenthesized arguments.

Also a possibility: Use the BOOST_PP_IF, BOOST_PP_EQUAL, and BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM to do something like:

```
MACRO(1, a)
MACRO(2, (a,b) )
MACRO(3, (a,b,c) )
```

or so.