# C++ Meta-programming

Tags: c++, templates, macros, metaprogramming

During development of my project in `C++` I have a frequent need of debugging and I usually use this macro to do it

```
#define DBUG(a) {std::cout << #a << " : " << a << std::endl;};
```

But many times I need to do something like this

```
int a;
std :: string b;
double c;
...
...
DBG(a); DBG(b); DBG(c);
```

But ideally it might be possible to just write `DBUG(a, b, c)` or `DBG(a, b, c, d, e)` for more variables to achieve something like this. After some research this looked like a problem in meta-programming or more specifically code-generation, but because of my limited knowledge in these areas I could not find a way to go about it.

If possible I would like to solve this without using Boost or other external libraries, and using the features in `C++98` although if it is not possible I'm willing to use `C++11`.

Comment: Title of this question is a little vague so, if you have a better idea, edit it.

Comment: Google for variadic macros, that should help you (and avoid `endl`, possibly reduce the number of calls to `operator<<` by using the preprocessor to concatenate strings...)

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `#define DBUG1(...) DBUG(arg1);DBUG(arg2);...;DBUG(argk);` using variadic macros

Comment: Why not use a debugger? They are pretty good at showing the value of variables.

Comment: True, I could use `gdb`, but I prefer old-school way of printing variables to debug. Both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Just let you know, it is not meta programming...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't like a limitation to a specific number of arguments. I didn't find a nice approach which decodes the name statically so the names are put together as a comma separated string and then decoded at run-time. Overall, that may be a bit too heavy-weight but, at least, it does as was asked and has not limitation on the number of arguments (other than compiler limitations, that is):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <int I, int S, typename... V>
typename std::enable_if<I == S>::type
debug_var(std::vector<std::string> const&, std::tuple<V...> const&)
{
}

template <int I, int S, typename... V>
typename std::enable_if<I != S>::type
debug_var(std::vector<std::string> const& n, std::tuple<V...> const& v)
{
    std::cout << n[I] << '=' << std::get<I>(v) << ' ';
    debug_var<I + 1, S>(n, v);
}

template <typename... V>
void debug(std::vector<std::string> const& n, std::tuple<V...> const& v)
{
    debug_var<0, sizeof...(V)>(n, v);
    std::cout << '\n' << std::flush;
}

std::vector<std::string> debug_names(char const* names)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::istringstream in(names);
    for (std::string name; std::getline(in >> std::ws, name, ','); ) {
        result.push_back(name);
    }
    return result;
}

#define DEBUG(...) debug(debug_names(#__VA_ARGS__), std::tie(__VA_ARGS__));

int main()
{
    int a=1, b=2;
    DEBUG(a, b);
    DEBUG();
}
```

The code uses several features which were introduced by the 2011 revision of C++.

Comment: Great! Clever use both macros and templates, although I'll have to spend a little more time to fully understand the code. It might be relevant to also mention that this works only for `C++11`.

Comment: Brilliant runtime solution if you ask me. Now I have to wonder if it's possible to process the names at compile time with one of those compile time string libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763277/962089). You have to define your macros to support up to a maximum number of parameters by changing the `CHOOSER` and `DBG` macros, as well as adding appropriate `DBG#` macros. It does require C++11, too.

```
#include <iostream>

#define DBG1(a) std::cout << #a ": " << a << "\n"
#define DBG2(a, b) DBG1(a); DBG1(b)
#define DBG3(a, b, c) DBG2(a, b); DBG1(c)

#define CHOOSER(a, b, c, CHOICE, ...) CHOICE
#define DBG(...) CHOOSER(__VA_ARGS__, DBG3, DBG2, DBG1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    int a{}, b{1}, c{5};
    DBG(a, b, c);
}
```

Output:

> a: 0
>   b: 1
>   c: 5

Comment: Yes, this works as long as I give up-to three arguments to `DBUG` macro, is it possible to make it work for arbitrary number of arguments like `DBUG(a, b, c, d, e)`.

Comment: @user2833292, Not unless you expand the macro definitions (so never arbitrary). Macros are pretty primitive. It will work with any number less than the maximum as well, though.

Comment: Then is it possible by using templates, I remember reading `C++` templates are Turing complete.

Comment: @user2833292: Turing complete doesn't imply being able to figure out the name of the variable/expression you are using in the argument.

Comment: @DanielKO Ok, I could have misunderstood, but then can we couple both macros and templates to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you may use your own `DBUG(a)` the following way

`DBUG(a << " " << b << " " << c);`

Answer (score -1):

How about using some good ol' C++11 variadic templates?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


template <typename T>
std::string make_string(const T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.str();
}

template <typename Thead, typename ... Ttail>
std::string make_string(const Thead& head, const Ttail& ... tail)
{
    return make_string(head) + make_string(tail...);
}

void debug(const std::string& msg)
{
    std::cout << "DEBUG: " << msg << std::endl;
}

void debug(void)
{
    std::cout << "DEBUG!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename ... Targs>
void debug(const Targs& ... args)
{
    debug(make_string(args...));
}



int main(void)
{
    int z;
    debug("We're gonna crash: ", &z, "!");
    debug();
    debug(3.14);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do what OP asked for, which printing both the name of the variable and its value.

Comment: Could be perfect if only we could have the name of variable printed.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that.