# How do I create an efficient closure using C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to capture the parameters passed to a function in a closure-like object. The main goal is to capture (store a reference not a copy) parameters of any type. (Here's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415845/a-better-log-macro-using-template-metaprogramming).)

Here's a very simplified version that only captures 2 parameters and stores them in a pair:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void foo(T1&& t1, T2&& t2)
{
    pair<T1&&, T2&&> p(forward(t1), forward(t2)); // Capture parameters -- doesn't work
    cout << p.first << "," << p.second << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "hey";
    foo("hello", "world");
    foo(1, 2);
    foo(s, endl);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile with g++ 4.7.2:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void foo(T1&&, T2&&) [with T1 = basic_string<char>&; T2 = basic_string<char>&]':
main.cpp: error: no matching function for call to 'forward(basic_string<char>&)'
...
```

How do I declare and initialize p to make the above compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify an explicit type for `std::forward`

`pair<T1&&, T2&&> p(forward<T1>(t1), forward<T2>(t2));`

The compiler won't be able to figure out the types of `endl` either if you want to use it like that, so they must be specified too `endl<char, char_traits<char>>`, you should probably be using `'\n'` anyway.