# Overloading a macro with two arguments

Tags: c, macros

I have a bunch of **#defines** that all look something like this **#define D, 0**, they contain a letter from A-D and  a number from 0-8, seperated by a comma.

Now I am trying to create a macro, like this: [Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments) ,but that would work with my case. The macros on this site only work for a #define with one argument, mine has two.

This is what I currently have:

```
#define GET_MACRO(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, NAME, ...) NAME
#define TEST_MACRO(...)     GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, _TEST_MACRO_8, _TEST_MACRO_7, _TEST_MACRO_6, _TEST_MACRO_5, _TEST_MACRO_4, _TEST_MACRO_3, _TEST_MACRO_2, _TEST_MACRO_1) (__VA_ARGS__)

#define _TEST_MACRO_8(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3, letter4, number4, letter5, number5, letter6, number6, letter7, number7, letter8, number8)           (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6) | (1 << number7) | (1 << number8))
#define _TEST_MACRO_7(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3, letter4, number4, letter5, number5, letter6, number6, letter7, number7)         (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6) | (1 << number7))
#define _TEST_MACRO_6(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3, letter4, number4, letter5, number5, letter6, number6)           (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6))
#define _TEST_MACRO_5(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3, letter4, number4, letter5, number5)         (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5))
#define _TEST_MACRO_4(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3, letter4, number4)           (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4))
#define _TEST_MACRO_3(letter1, number1, letter2, number2, letter3, number3)         (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3))
#define _TEST_MACRO_2(letter1, number1, letter2, number2)           (PORT##letter1 |= ((1 << number1) | (1 << number2))
#define _TEST_MACRO_1(letter1, number1)         (PORT##letter1 |= (1 << number1))
```

If I do:

```
#define ONE    D, 0
#define TWO    D, 1
#define THREE  D, 2

TEST_MACRO(ONE); //Error: macro _TEST_MACRO_2 requires 4 arguments but only 2 given
TEST_MACRO(ONE,TWO); //Error: macro _TEST_MACRO_4 requires 8 arguments but only 4 given
TEST_MACRO(ONE,TWO,THREE); //Error: macro _TEST_MACRO_6 requires 12 arguments but only 6 given
```

What is the problem here? How can I solve it?

Best regards!

**EDIT:**

To clarify a bit, here is the background where this is gonna get used in. I am programming a 8-bit AVR microcontrollers. And right know I have pins defined this way: `#define PIN1 A,0`, where **A** represents the PINs letter and **0** represents the PINs number.

If I have a whole bunch of them defined this way, when I want to change some setting of them, I have to do it manually one by one, like so: `PIN_HIGH(PIN1);PIN_HIGH(PIN2);PIN_HIGH(PIN3)` and with more of them, the code gets quite messy.

So I am looking for a way to do it with one macro: `PIN_HIGH(PIN1,PIN2,PIN3);`. It is also important that the `PIN1,PIN2,PIN3` letters match when I am passing them to a macro, because sometimes, I could move the pin to some otherletter.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this are more than welcome!

Comment: I can't think of a better way to do it... Any improvements are more than welcome!

Comment: Its alot easier to read: PIN_HIGH(PIN_1,PIN_2,PIN_8); than PORTA |= ((1<<PA1) | (1<<PA2) |(1<<PA8)), and keeping track of all the PORTS and DDRS, and PINS its just a lot more work than doing this, at least in my oppinion. But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I'm certain you could do it more cleanly than your second example, and almost anything would be better than having to guess to see which macro is actually being expanded. But as I said, I'm not going to be the one working with it, so clearly it's your decision. You *did* ask, however. :-)

Comment: `#define D, 0` is an odd way to define a macro. The macro name is `D`, and the `,` is the first token of the expansion. Why not insert a space? `#define D , 0`

Comment: I am sorry, its a typo. I meant #define PIN D,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character that represents the port is not used other than the first. So, I suggest that following way.

```
#define GET_MACRO(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, NAME, ...) NAME
#define TEST_MACRO(letter,...)  (PORT##letter |=  GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, _TEST_MACRO_8, _TEST_MACRO_7, _TEST_MACRO_6, _TEST_MACRO_5, _TEST_MACRO_4, _TEST_MACRO_3, _TEST_MACRO_2, _TEST_MACRO_1) (__VA_ARGS__) )

#define _TEST_MACRO_8(number1, number2, number3,  number4,  number5,  number6,  number7, number8) \
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6) | (1 << number7) | (1 << number8)
#define _TEST_MACRO_7(number1, number2, number3,  number4,  number5,  number6,  number7)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6) | (1 << number7)
#define _TEST_MACRO_6(number1, number2, number3,  number4,  number5,  number6)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5) | (1 << number6)
#define _TEST_MACRO_5(number1, number2, number3,  number4,  number5)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4) | (1 << number5)
#define _TEST_MACRO_4(number1, number2, number3,  number4)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3) | (1 << number4)
#define _TEST_MACRO_3(number1, number2, number3)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2) | (1 << number3)
#define _TEST_MACRO_2(number1, number2)\
    (1 << number1) | (1 << number2)
#define _TEST_MACRO_1(number1)\
    (1 << number1)


TEST_MACRO(D, 1);
TEST_MACRO(D, 0, 1);
TEST_MACRO(D, 0, 1, 2);

#define ONE    (D, 0)
#define TWO    (D, 1)
#define THREE  (D, 2)
#define CAR(a,b) a
#define CDR(a,b) b
#define F(x) CAR x
#define R(x) CDR x 
#define TEST_MACRO_WRAP(...) TEST_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__)
TEST_MACRO_WRAP(F(ONE), R(ONE));
TEST_MACRO_WRAP(F(ONE), R(ONE), R(TWO));
TEST_MACRO_WRAP(F(ONE), R(ONE), R(TWO), R(THREE));
```

Comment: I really like this, but is there a way to pass in whole **ONE**, **TWO**, **THREE** #defines without having to pass parts of them, like letter and number from **ONE**, then only number from **TWO**. And then, is it possible to check in a macro if all letters passed are the same, and throw a #error if they're not? Thanks!

Comment: This check to see if all letters are the same would have to be done  at compile time, because I have very limited resources avalible. Thank you again!

Comment: @user1806687 It can not be compared for equality of non-numeric  in the preprocessor.

Comment: I dont know if this makes any difference, but letters are part of an enum: 

typedef enum PIN_LETTERS {
 A,
 B,
 C,
 D
} letters_t;

Comment: @user1806687 You can not directly use a type or variable that is defined in the C program in the preprocessor. It may be possible to embed the code, but may be defined as a function if it. also not compile time check.

Comment: As the idea of one, It can cause a compilation error when it is not the same identifier to the following  `#define TEST(a, b) int a; b;`. but It is believed that the location that can be used is limited to it to cause harm rather.

Answer (score 0):

The macros `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE` are all expanded immediately before expanding `TEST_MACRO`, so when you say `TEST_MACRO(ONE)`, the `__VA_ARGS__` macro arg is set to `D, 0` (the expansion of `ONE`), which means you call `_TEST_MACRO_2`, as that is two arguments.

Since you always want an even number of arguments, you could define `TEST_MACRO` as:

```
#define TEST_MACRO(...)     GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, _TEST_MACRO_4, ERROR, _TEST_MACRO_3, ERROR, _TEST_MACRO_2, ERROR, _TEST_MACRO_1, ERROR) (__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERROR(...)    #error "Odd number of arguments to TEST_MACRO"
```

Comment: I will try it out tommorow and let you know. Since ts preety late here,where I live.