# how to substitute function using macro in C

Tags: c, macros

Sometimes, in a C code I borrowed from a linux driver, I want to change some macros into a function that I can use in my environment.  But this previous macro can take 3 or 4 arguments.
For example, if I want to substite

```
SMSC_TRACE(pdata, probe, "Driver Parameters:");   // 3 arguments
```

into

```
printf("Driver Parameters:");
```

and substitute

```
SMSC_TRACE(pdata, probe, "LAN base: 0x%08lX", (unsigned long)pdata->ioaddr); // 4 arguments
```

into

```
printf("LAN base: 0x%08lX", (unsigned long)pdata->ioaddr);
```

How do I do that? I tried

```
#define SMSC_TRACE((a), (b), (c)) printf((c))  
#define SMSC_TRACE((a), (b), (c), (d)) printf((c), (d))
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Only the last one seems to take effect.

EDIT: this seems it maybe.

```
#define SMSC_TRACE(pdata, nlevel, fmt, args...) printf(fmt "\n", ##args)
```

Comment: What compiler you use? GCC has a solution.

Comment: @leppie please tell me. (maybe I could see the original definition of SMSC_TRACE above :))

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a [variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), which takes a variable number of arguments:

```
#define SMSC_TRACE(a,b,...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

If you want this macro to execute multiple statements, then you need a `do/while(0)`.

For example:

```
#define SMSC_TRACE(a,b,...) \
do                          \
{                           \
    printf("%c\n",a);       \
    printf("%d\n",b);       \
    printf(__VA_ARGS__);    \
}                           \
while (0)
```