# Can gfortran allocate with MOLD or not?

Tags: macos, gfortran, allocation

I am trying to compile a fairly modern fortran code on a Mac with gfortran.  Lines like this one ...

```
allocate(sce, mold=sct)
```

get errors like this:

```
Error: Array specification or array-valued SOURCE= expression required in ALLOCATE statement
```

It seems, then, that gfortran understands `SOURCE` but not `MOLD`. However, my gfortran is recent:

```
 gcc version 8.2.0 (MacPorts gcc8 8.2.0_3)
```

I have seen web pages claiming that gfortran has been able to support `MOLD` since version 7.something.  So surely it should be able to do it with 8.2.0.  Is this not true?  Is something funny about the Mac version?  Can anyone suggest what some other problem might be?

EDIT:  If anyone's still there, this toy code works fine:

```
program awm

integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: sct,sce

integer :: nspec = 100

allocate(sct(nspec))
allocate(sce, mold=sct)

end program
```

But when sct and sce are derived types, it falls apart:

```
program awm

type :: r1d
    real, allocatable :: a(:)
end type

type(r1d), dimension(:), allocatable :: sct,sce

integer :: nspec = 100

allocate(sct(nspec))
do i = 1,nspec
  allocate(sct(i)%a(10))
enddo 
allocate(sce, mold=sct)

end program
```

This returns the error I was having above.  You might think the definition of the derived type is kind of weird, even unnecessary.  Well, the original code from which this is taken is not my code and I'm not in a position to change it much, and actually, this structuring does have its uses for reasons I don't have time to go into.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not about supooting mold, it is about the missing array spec. This was a known bug, but shoud be fixed by now https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44672

Comment: I can't see a problem (using 7.3 on Linux) with either a test program I wrote or that of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384145/3157076).  So, please produce a complete example (it could be there's an issue in the code) for us to explore further.  (It'll then also be worth adding the tag [tag:fortran].)

Comment: Your code (with obvious necessary extensions) compiles OK with GCC 6 and 7, it causes the mentioned error in GCC 5. Tested on Linux.

Comment: GCC 8 compiles as well.

Comment: @VladimirF  But AFAICT, I have GCC 8 myself here.  So is there something wrong/out-of-date with the version I have, somehow?  Are you testing on a Mac, by chance?  Thanks.

Comment: No, everything is on Linux, but the well-known bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44672 was fixed a long time ago. Please check your are really compiling with the right gfortran executable. You may have multiple versions installed (I have all these 4 versions + one older as the system GCC).

Comment: Well, now you can see why we need a MCVE.So much time just wasted...

Comment: I am not sure this is supposed to work, but probably yes because ifort does compile it. Time to file a GCC bugreport.

Comment: Yes, this is a compiler bug, but a different one from the previous.

Comment: Still a bug in gfortran 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am convinced this is a duplicate of this GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80708 or is very closely related. You have to wait for a fix. I will put your code in the comment for this bug and not open a new one.