# C: Consecutive macros don't work

Tags: c, macros

I have a function that displays a string on the screen. The prototype is `dispStrFont(char* str, struct Font font, int x, int y, int color)`.

However since it is annoying to type the font, I made a macro `#define dispStr(str, x, y, color) dispStrFont(str, normal_font, x, y, color)`. Seems to work fine when compiling (no errors).

Most of my strings are black, so there's no need for me to type the color. So I made the color optional with another macro (placed before the above one): `#define dispStr(str, x, y) dispStr(str, x, y, 0)`.

The combination of those two macros give errors, and I don't know why.

Header file:

```
#define dispStr(str, x, y) dispStr(str, x, y, 0)
#define dispStr(str, x, y, color) dispStrFont(str, normal_font, x, y, color)
//the define above gives me a warning: "Incompatible redefinition of macro "dispStr" (declared at line 1)"
```

Main file:

```
dispStr("test", x, y) //gives me an error, saying there's an illegal token ')'
                      //also gives me a warning "Too few arguments in macro invocation"
dispStr("test", x, y, 0) //compiles fine
```

Why does it behaves that way? Also, when I comment the second define, it doesn't give me that parenthesis error (but it doesn't compile obviously because it doesn't recognize the `dispStr` function), so it's the consecutive defines on `dispStr(str, x, y)` that cause the error.

Edit: ended up modifying the macros to remove the unnecessary combination. So `define dispStr(str, x, y) dispStr(str, x, y, 0)` becomes `define dispStr(str, x, y) dispStrFont(str, normal_font, x, y, 0)`. I also had to put that define after the other one, else it still gave me the parenthesis error for some reason.

Comment: Did you try switching the orders?

Comment: If I switch the defines it doesn't work because then `dispStr(str, x, y)` is replaced by `dispStr(str, x, y, 0)` but not then replaced by `dispStrFont`.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I had a brainfart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Don't give the macros the same name? What made you think that was a good idea for any purpose? It's like posting on some parent guidance forums: "I named all my 5 kids Bob, but I have a problem: they all reply at once when I call for Bob. What should I do?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't overload the macros. Moreover if a macro is invoked already, it is not invoked again.

You should give different names to your macro. Also you can use [variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) supported as GNU extension and in C99 onwards.