# Portably detect __VA_OPT__ support?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++20

In C++20, the preprocessor supports [`__VA_OPT__`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0306r4.html) as a way to optionally expand tokens in a variadic macro if the number of arguments is greater than zero. (This obviates the need for the `##__VA_ARGS__` GCC extension, which is a non-portable and ugly hack.)

Clang SVN has implemented this feature, but they haven't added a feature test macro for it. Can any clever preprocessor hacker figure out a way to detect the presence or absence of `__VA_OPT__` support without causing a hard error or a portability warning?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Inspired by [chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045586).<sup>1</sup>

```
#define PP_THIRD_ARG(a,b,c,...) c
#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(...) PP_THIRD_ARG(__VA_OPT__(,),true,false,)
#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(?)
```

If `__VA_OPT__` is supported, `VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(?)` expands to `PP_THIRD_ARG(,,true,false,)`, so the third argument is `true`; otherwise, `VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(?)` expands to `PP_THIRD_ARG(__VA_OPT__(,),true,false,)`, the third argument is `false`.

---

Edit: As [Edward Diener's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168986) notes, GCC >= 8 issues a warning or error whenever it sees `__VA_OPT__`, if `-pedantic` mode is on and `__VA_OPT__` is not enabled (e.g. in `-std=c++17`). This is [GCC bug 98859](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98859). One might have to special-case GCC to avoid this diagnostic.

```
#if __cplusplus <= 201703 && defined __GNUC__ \
  && !defined __clang__ && !defined __EDG__ // These compilers pretend to be GCC
#  define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED false
#endif
```

---

<sup>1. As chris mentions, if `__VA_OPT__(,)` expands to `,`, there will be 2 empty arguments, otherwise there will be 1 argument. So it's possible to test `PP_NARG(__VA_OPT__(,)) == 2`, where [`PP_NARG` is a macro to count the number of arguments](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/d-6Mj5Lko_s). To adapt to this test, the definition of `PP_NARG` can be simplified and inlined.</sup>

Comment: This is the kind of brevity I was imagining when I said mine could probably be improved. Nice work :)

Answer (score 11):

Something like the following should work, though you might be able to improve it:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_II_1(_) 0
#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_II_2(_1, _2) 1

#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(...) BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_II_, __VA_OPT__(,))(__VA_OPT__(,))

#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(?)
```

On Clang trunk, this evaluates to 1 in C++2a mode and 0 in C++17 mode. GCC trunk actually evaluates this to 1 in C++17, but also handles `__VA_OPT__` in that mode.

What this does is use `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD` to call either the `_1` or `_2` version of `_II` based on the count of arguments. If `__VA_OPT__(,)` expands to `,`, there will be 2 empty arguments. If not, there will be 1 empty argument. We always call this macro with an argument list, so any compiler supporting `__VA_OPT__` should always expand it to `,`.

Naturally, the Boost.PP dependency isn't mandatory. A simple 1-or-2-arg `OVERLOAD` macro should be easy enough to replace. Losing a bit of generality to make it more straightforward:

```
#define OVERLOAD2_I(_1, _2, NAME, ...) NAME
#define OVERLOAD2(NAME1, NAME2, ...) OVERLOAD2_I(__VA_ARGS__, NAME2, NAME1)

#define VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_I(...) OVERLOAD2(VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_II_1, VA_OPT_SUPPORTED_II_2, __VA_OPT__(,))(__VA_OPT__(,))
```

There is one portability warning from Clang:

> warning: variadic macros are incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat-pedantic]

I don't know if this detection is even possible without C++11 variadic macro support. You could consider assuming no support for `__cplusplus` values lower than C++11, but Clang still gives the warning even when wrapped in such a check.

Comment: I would love to accept this answer, but I need no dependencies, and I don't have the PP skills to implement `OVERLOAD`. Care to remove the Boost.PP dependence?

Comment: @EricNiebler, Sure. In the meantime, there are several SO questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments).

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the solution as it is specified in its most popular answer above is that the compiler is free to issue a warning, or even an error, if __VA_OPT__ is used outside of its C++20 mode, since the word is a compiler reserved word since it starts and ends with double underscores. In fact I have discovered that gcc will issue a warning or an error depending on the compiler options being used, although it will normally not do so in most compiling cases. Because of this surrounding any solution with a current test for C++20, such as:

```
# if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus > 201703L
// Solution
#endif
```

is a more conservative solution although it limits the test to C++20 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can write your own `OVERLOAD` macro. `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD` consists of two parts, `BOOST_PP_CAT` and `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE`. However, unlike Boost, you only care about 2 args. So:

```
#define OVERLOAD(prefix, ...) CAT(prefix, VARIADIC(__VA_ARGS__))
```

`CAT` will look like:

```
#define CAT(a, b) KITTY((a, b))
#define KITTY(par) MEOW ## par
#define MEOW(a, b) a ## b
```

And `VARIADIC`:

```
#define VARIADIC(...) _VARIADIC_(__VA_ARGS__, 2, 1,)
#define _VARIADIC_(e0, e1, size, ...) size
```