# C macro that detects empty argument and then uses default case

Tags: c, macros

I have macros that will either expand into a number (in my example, cases 2 and 4), or nothing (in my example, cases 1 and 3). Nothingness isn't desirable for me, so I need other macros that will detect and replace the nothingness.

I was able to create a macro, `OLD_CHECK`, that would detect the nothingness-case and replace it with a 0. (Case 1)

I want to improve on it and create a new macro, `NEW_CHECK`, that will detect the nothingness-case and replace it with a default value. (Case 3)

```
/* what I currently have */
print("case 1: [%d]", OLD_CHECK( ));                   // case 1: [0]
print("case 2: [%d]", OLD_CHECK(5));                   // case 2: [5]

/* what I hope to achieve */
int default_value = 7;
print("case 3: [%d]", NEW_CHECK(default_value,  ));    // case 3: [7]
print("case 4: [%d]", NEW_CHECK(default_value, 5));    // case 4: [5]
```

To write `OLD_CHECK`, I was using the number of arguments. This method does not seem to feasible to write `NEW_CHECK` with, as cases 3 and 4 are both detected as having 2 arguments.

Edit: this is the macro that works to catch and handle Cases 1 and 2:

```
/* Given a dummy and >=1 arguments, expand to the first argument */
#define FIRST_ONE(dummy, a1, ...) a1
/* if "..." is nonblank, expand to the first arg of "...". otherwise, expand to 0 */
#define OLD_CHECK(...) OLD_CHECK_CORE(__VA_ARGS__) 
#define OLD_CHECK_CORE(...) FIRST_ONE(dummy, ##__VA_ARGS__, 0)
```

Edit 2: It is necessary to have the trailing comma in Case 3. It is an unfortunate byproduct of a series of other more-complicated macros.

ANSWERED:
[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650578/13837464), given by p00ya, works for me:

```
#define NEW_CHECK_HELPER(...) , ## __VA_ARGS__
#define NEW_CHECK(default, ...) (default NEW_CHECK_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: Put the macro in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GCC's `, ## __VA_ARGS__` extension for comma-deletion (which you are already using for `OLD_CHECK`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEW_CHECK_HELPER(...) , ## __VA_ARGS__
#define NEW_CHECK(default, ...) (default NEW_CHECK_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__))

int
main() {
  int default_value = 7;
  printf("case 3: %d\n", NEW_CHECK(default_value, ));
  printf("case 4: %d\n", NEW_CHECK(default_value, 5));
}
```

Prints:

```
case 3: 7
case 4: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to support the "empty argument" in case 3, then you can try the non-portable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEW_CHECK(default, ...) (default __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))

int
main() {
  int default_value = 7;
  printf("case 3: %d\n", NEW_CHECK(default_value, ));
  printf("case 4: %d\n", NEW_CHECK(default_value, 5));
}
```

When compiled with recent versions of gcc (e.g. 10.1, see https://godbolt.org/z/AhST8m), this will print:

```
case 3: 7
case 4: 5
```

It relies on the non-standard `__VA_OPT__`, which is being [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0306r4.html#wg14) for C, but is supported as a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

I would question your requirement to include the trailing comma in case 3, though.

Comment: Thank you; my problem does need to handle the trailing comma. Unfortunately, the non-portability of the solution is an issue. My environment does not support `__VA_OPT__`, which I tested with both my problem child and with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045656/13837464).

Comment: Fair enough; I added a second answer that uses GCC's `,##__VA_ARGS__` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing method will work if you get rid of the trailing comma in case three:

```
#define FIRST_ONE(dummy, a1, ...) a1
#define NEW_CHECK(DEFAULT, ...) FIRST_ONE(dummy,##__VA_ARGS__, DEFAULT)

/* what I hope to achieve */
int default_value = 7;
print("case 3: [%d]", NEW_CHECK(default_value  ));    // case 3: [7]
print("case 4: [%d]", NEW_CHECK(default_value, 5));    // case 4: [5]
```

The reason is that GCC makes a distinction between *no argument* and an *empty argument* for `,##__VA_ARGS__` -- only if there is *no* argument does it remove the comma -- a (single) empty argument keeps it.

Then there's the strangeness that `OLD_CHECK( )` is treated as *no argument* rather than an *empty argument*, which arguably doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I came up with an alternative many-step solution that is equally portable as `OLD_CHECK`. It reuses `FIRST_ONE` from before, and also uses a standard `NARGS` macro to count the number of arguments in `__VA_ARGS__`.

```
/* NEW_CHECK(default, maybe_blank) */
#define NEW_CHECK(...) M_(__VA_ARGS__)
/* delay expansion of M once to perform Q */
#define M_(D, ...) F(D, Q(__VA_ARGS__))
/* Q(maybe_blank): if __VA_ARGS__ is non-blank, __VA_ARGS__. Otherwise, SPACE */
#define Q(...) FIRST_ONE(dummy, ##__VA_ARGS__, SPACE)
/* SPACE just expands into two arguments so that we can differentiate between was-blank (2 args) and non-blank (1 arg) */
#define SPACE 0, 0
/* F(default, one-or-two-arguments) */
#define F(...) F_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define F_(...) F__(__VA_ARGS__)
/* delay expansion of F twice, for performing Q and SPACE */
#define F__(D, ...) H(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), D, __VA_ARGS__)
/* H(1 or 2, default, maybe_blank) */
#define H(...) H_(__VA_ARGS__)
/* delay expansion once, for performing NARGS */
#define H_(N, D, ...) DO##N(D, __VA_ARGS__)
/* based on NARGS, pick correct result */
#define DO1(D, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define DO2(D, ...) D
```

However, this ugly monstrosity is not necessary, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650578/13837464) works for me as well, and is so much cleaner. Thank you all very much!