# Overload C Macros with _minimal_ rows

Tags: c++, c, c++11, macros, overloading

Not complicated way to overload MACROS with null,one,two arguments

based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments/11763277#11763277) 
I want to overload one/two arguments and if possible 0 argument, but with minimal rows of macros.

Now I did in the following mode

```
// For 1..2 arguments, we get 4 rows
#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2, NAME,...) NAME
#define FOO(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FOO2, FOO1)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO1(x) ABC(F(x))
#define FOO2(x,y) ABC(F(x), F(y))

FOO(x)  ->  ABC(F(x))
```

but I have two questions

1. is it possible to do this with less then 4 rows ?
2. <strike>is it possible to make overload for 0 arg in the following mode</strike>

   ```
   FOO() -> ABC()
   ```

**Update:** 2nd question is not actual any more. So now I have for 0..2 arg - 5 rows. For 1..2 arg - 4 rows. So each additional func_n_arg()  need to have separate converter + 2 rows for counting arguments. Is it possible to do with less rows of macros? for the same thing

Comment: Do you think four rows is very much? And did the answers that question not address the case of 0 args?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)

Comment: @L. F. <br>My four rows is not include 0 arg.<br>If possible to do the same thing with 3 rows why we should use 4 rows method :)

Comment: @L. F. and its not duplicate of *your link*  its based on. I mentioned this in first post. In this link author only want to overload to many different functions. In my case I need only one function but with different number of arguments AND with minimal count of macro rows </br> Sorry for my english and Im not professional programmer

Comment: If you want to handle 0..N arguments, you need N+1 macros with a numeric suffix and 2 more to handle the counting and provide the generic interface.  You can't get it smaller than that.  Why do you think the number of macros is a problem?  Unless you start going up to hundreds of arguments, it isn't going to stress a compiler (but it might stress you as the author).  And hundreds of them probably isn't going to cause the compiler much problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeh, its stress for author from one side, from other I expect small code for small task :)
sorry for my english