# Macro with number of arguments AND default parameter

Tags: c, c99, variadic-macros

I'm familiar with [the following way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments) of creating a macro with variable number of arguments. However, consider:

```
#define MY_MACRO_N(value, format, ...) my_func(value, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define MY_MACRO_0(value) my_func(value, NULL)
```

Where `my_func` takes variable number of arguments as well. How can I create a `MY_MACRO` macro that encapsulates both, such that:

```
MY_MACRO(my_value);  // expand to my_func(my_value, NULL);
MY_MACRO(my_value, my_format);  // expand to my_func(my_value, my_format);
MY_MACRO(my_value, my_format, a, b);  // expand to my_func(my_value, my_format, a, b);
MY_MACRO();  // invalid
```

The variable number of arguments break the `GET_MACRO` approach, however it seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: Do you want your macro to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, or is there some fixed upper bound on argument count?

Comment: No upper bound, as `my_func` has no upper bound.

Comment: Then I think you're stuck.  To the best of my knowledge, all potential approaches to problems of this kind have a built-in maximum on the number of arguments they can handle.  You can make that maximum large (typically via large preprocessor code), but you cannot avoid it altogether.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It looks promising because I only really care about the second argument - the rest is going `my_func` as is.

Comment: If this is a logging macro with `printf`-like syntax (and it looks like it) and if you are willing to accept an empty string as default instead of `NULL` and if you are okay with restricting the format of literal strings if it is given, you can make use of string-literal concatenation. In this special, but common case, the macro looks like `#define LOG(CODE, ...) my_func(CODE, "" __VA_ARGS__)`. (But the format checker will complain about empty format strings, so that may not be a good solution.)

Comment: @MOehm I can't seem to understand how that helps, seems like your solution rely on passing a pre-formatted string instead of `format` and additional arguments. I need something stronger then that.

Comment: Well, `LOG(X)` expands to `my_func(X, "")`, anything else to `my_func(X, "" "<fmt>", ...)`, which will paste the empty string to your format string, [see here](https://ideone.com/VWs3Mc). That will only work if your format string is a literal, but that's usually the case. Never mind. It was just a suggestion that you might have found useful.

Comment: @MOehm Got it, and it actually might work for my scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you overload a macro on number of arguments, be it using an argument list or `EVAL(..)` recursive expansion, there is always a maximum number of arguments it can handle. You can only set up an unrealistic limit - 64? 256? 1000? - and generate the overloads for that many macro arguments.

```
#define MY_MACRO_0()                    MY_MACRO_1(will do an error
#define MY_MACRO_1(value)               my_func(value, NULL)
#define MY_MACRO_V(value, format, ...)  my_func(value, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define MY_MACRO_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,_0,N,...)  MY_MACRO_##N
#define MY_MACRO(...)  MY_MACRO_N(0,##__VA_ARGS__,V,V,V,1,0)(__VA_ARGS__)
MY_MACRO(my_value);  // expand to my_func(my_value, NULL);
MY_MACRO(my_value, my_format);  // expand to my_func(my_value, my_format);
MY_MACRO(my_value, my_format, a, b);  // expand to my_func(my_value, my_format, a, b);
MY_MACRO();  // invalid
```

Still, as noted in the commands, for logging functions it's typical to pass an empty string literal in case of missing format string, then just check `if (*fmt == '\0')` in the logging function.

```
#define MY_MACRO(value, ...)   my_func(value, "" __VA_ARGS__)
```