# How to write a macro that will be expanded to define an object with template parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-macros

Is it possible to write a macro, which, in turn, creates an object definition from it, for example:

```
DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES(ObjectType, double, int, 1.0, 1)
```

should become:

```
ObjectType a<double, int>(1.0, 1);
```

and

```
DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES(ObjectType, double, int, bool, 1.0, 1, false)
```

should become:

```
ObjectType a<double, int, bool>(1.0, 1, false);
```

Comment: Why not use a templated factory function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [overload a macro on number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments):

```
#define DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_2(T1, V1)  \
        a<T1>(V1)
#define DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_4(T1, T2, V1, V2)  \
        a<T1, T2>(V1, V2)
#define DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_6(T1, T2, T3, V1, V2, V3)  \
        a<T1, T2, T3>(V1, V2, V3)
#define DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...)  \
        DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_##N
#define DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES(objecttype, ...)  \
        objecttype DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES_N(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

// will expand to:
// ObjectType a<double, int>(1.0, 1)
DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES(ObjectType, double, int, 1.0, 1) 

// will expand to:
// ObjectType a<double, int, bool>(1.0, 1, false)
DEFINE_OBJECT_INVALID_VALUES(ObjectType, double, int, bool, 1.0, 1, false)
```