# C++ Overloading macro on undefined number of arguments

Tags: c++

My command uses return codes and a string reference argument instead of exceptions to detect an error in the execution of a function.

We have some invariant checking that looks like this:

```
bool format(std::string &error, ...)
{
    // call sprintf on "error" string with all passed arguments
    return false;
}

bool func(std::string &error)
{
    // .......................
    
    if (!some_expression)
        return format(error, /*some undefined number of args*/);    
    
    // .......................
}
```

I want to write a macro, that will perform this logic in one line like this:

```
REQUIRE(expr, functor, "test string");
REQUIRE(expr, functor, "number=%lld", 1ll);
REQUIRE(expr, functor, "number_1=%lld, number_2=%f", 1ll, 2.0);
```

When REQUIRE macro will be this:

```
#define REQUIRE(expression, functor, format, ...)   \
{                                                   \
    if (!expression)                                \
        return functor(format, __VA_ARGS__)         \
}
```

But this solution doesn't work, when i pass only format string without any arguments (first case in example). I tryed all solutions from this question:
[Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments), but all of them requires writing overloading on all agrs count.

Here is my non-working code code for now:

```
#define REQUIRE_1(expression, functor, format)  \
{                                               \
    if (!expression)                            \
        return functor(format);                 \
} 

#define REQUIRE_2(expression, functor, format, ...) \
{                                                   \
    if (!expression)                                \
        return functor(format, __VA_ARGS__)         \
}   

#define GET_MACRO(_1, _2, _3, NAME, ...) NAME
#define REQUIRE(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, REQUIRE_1, REQUIRE_2)(__VA_ARGS__)
                                        
bool functor(const char *format, ...)
{
    // Here is passing args to something like printf

    return false;
}


bool format(std::string &error, ...)
{
    // call sprintf on "error" string with all passed arguments
    return false;
}

bool func(std::string &error)
{
    // .......................

    if (!some_expression)
        return format(error, /*some undefined number of args*/);    

    // .......................
}



int main()
{
    REQUIRE(true, func, "test string");
    REQUIRE(true, func, "number=%lld", 1ll);
    REQUIRE(true, func, "number_1=%lld, number_2=%f", 1ll, 2.0);
    // Samples for [5,6,7..infinite] arguments
}
```

How can i achieve needed behaviour?

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++?  The C++ language allows overloading of functions, and the C language doesn't.  Pretty important here.  Please update your language tags accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I wouldn't change the tags. Leaving both C and C++ is perfectly acceptable if the goal is to have a solution that works in both languages. And for macros, this is a perfectly reasonable requirement if there exists a macro solution that works in both languages, and most macro solutions indeed do work in both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20 made it possible to call `#define F(x, y, ...)` as `F(1, 2)`, without the comma after the last argument.

If C++20 is available, the only change you need to do is to replace `, __VA_ARGS__` with `__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__` to the remove the comma if no extra arguments are passed.

Otherwise, just combine `format` and `...` parameters into a single `...` parameter.