# How can a variadic macro with a list of types produce a function which accepts those arguments and passes them along?

Tags: c++, c++11, preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have a macro:

```
#define WRAP_FUNCTION(wrapper_name, function, ret_type, arg1_type, arg2_type, ...)
```

And I would like it to define a function like this:

```
ret_type wrapper_name(arg1_type arg1, arg2_type arg2, ...) {
    return function(arg1, arg2, ...)
}
```

Except where the ellipses (along with arg1 and arg2) are a dynamically sized list.  I could create the function prototype using `__VA_ARGS__`, but that doesn't give me names for the arguments to pass to the wrapped function.

I assume the usual approach would be `std::apply` (or to copy-paste the implementation of `std::apply`, since it's not available in C++11).  Unfortunately the argument `function` may be overloaded or a compiler built-in so it cannot reliably be passed as a function type.

What I have right now is the generation of a variadic template function:

```
template<class... Args>
ret_type wrapper_name(Args... args) {
    return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But this causes a world of problems with conversions because there's a lot that cannot be done with implicit conversions in this form when the wrapped function is overloaded.  It also can't wrap function-like macros, but I think addressing that problem may be impossible anyway.

---

Update: With a bit of fiddling I can make the wrapper function enforce its argument types this way:

```
#define WRAPPER(name, ret_type, function, ...) \
  template<class... Args> struct name##_impl { static inline \
  ret_type func(Args... args) { return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } }; \
  template<class... Args> ret_type name(Args... args) \
  { return name##_impl<__VA_ARGS__>::func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

Unfortunately, this leaves me with the problem that I cannot overload the identifier `name` with different argument lists.  My attempts at making the `name` template a specialisation have resulted in a lot of complaints either about *partial* specialisation of a function or about not forwarding any template arguments to the generic template.

Comment: It seems like making the variadic template and then following with: `#define wrapper_name wrapper_template<__VA_ARGS__>` would solve it, but that's obviously impossible.

Comment: Your variadic template function should use `std::forward`, eg: `template<class... Args> ret_type wrapper_name(Args... args) { return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau updated.  It doesn't affect what I'm doing, but updated all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variadic macro to generate a *non-template* wrapper, you can use some [macro tricks](https://codecraft.co/2014/11/25/variadic-macros-tricks/), specifically [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763277/65863), to generate your argument list **with names** so you can call your target function, eg:

```
// this example supports functions that have 0..3 arguments,
// you can expand this for more arguments if needed...

#define _ARG_PARAMS3(type1, type2, type3) type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3
#define _ARG_NAMES3(type1, type2, type3) arg1, arg2, arg3

#define _ARG_PARAMS2(type1, type2) type1 arg1, type2 arg2
#define _ARG_NAMES2(type1, type2) arg1, arg2

#define _ARG_PARAMS1(type1) type1 arg1
#define _ARG_NAMES1(type1) arg1

#define _ARG_PARAMS0()
#define _ARG_NAMES0()

#define _GET_OVERRIDE(_1, _2, _3, _4, NAME, ...) NAME

#define ARG_PARAMS(...) _GET_OVERRIDE("ignored", __VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) \
    _ARG_PARAMS3, _ARG_PARAMS2, _ARG_PARAMS1, _ARG_PARAMS0)(__VA_ARGS__)
    
#define ARG_NAMES(...) _GET_OVERRIDE("ignored", __VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) \
    _ARG_NAMES3, _ARG_NAMES2, _ARG_NAMES1, _ARG_NAMES0)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define WRAP_FUNCTION(wrapper_name, function, ret_type, ...) \
ret_type wrapper_name(ARG_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)) { \
    return function(ARG_NAMES(__VA_ARGS__)); \
}
```

And then you can use `WRAP_FUNCTION` like you want:

```
int funcWith3Args(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    ...
}

string funcWithNoArgs()
{
    ...
}

WRAP_FUNCTION(wrapper3Args, funcWith3Args, int, int, int, int)
WRAP_FUNCTION(wrapperNoArgs, funcWithNoArgs, string)

...

wrapper3Args(1, 2, 3);
wrapperNoArgs();

...
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2MRjT7i17)

With some tweaking, I'm sure you can also generate a template wrapper, too.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's possible to convert a list of function arguments into a template parameter pack by specialising a template which accepts a function signature:

```
#define WRAP(NAME, CALLEE, SIGNATURE) \
    using NAME##_sig = SIGNATURE; \
    template<class T> struct NAME##_impl; \
    template<class Ret, class... Args> \
    struct NAME##_impl<Ret(Args...)> { \
        Ret operator()(Args... args) const noexcept \
        { return CALLEE(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }; \
    }; \
    constexpr NAME##_impl<NAME##_sig> NAME;

void example(char *, size_t);
WRAP(test, example, void(char*, size_t))
void fn(char*x, size_t y) { test(x, y); }
```

So, if a list of macro arguments is what's preferred:

```
#define WRAP2(NAME, CALLEE, RET, ...) \
    using NAME##_sig = RET(__VA_ARGS__); \
    template<class T> struct NAME##_impl; \
    template<class Ret, class... Args> \
    struct NAME##_impl<Ret(Args...)> { \
        Ret operator()(Args... args) const noexcept \
        { return CALLEE(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }; \
    }; \
    constexpr NAME##_impl<NAME##_sig> NAME;

void example(char *, size_t);
WRAP(test, example, void, char*, size_t)
void fn(char*x, size_t y) { test(x, y); }
```

This makes it possible to define a functor with the desired signature, and also to address the complete list of arguments within the implementation as `args...` so that they can all be passed through to the function being wrapped.

Overloading of functors can be implemented by making them all ancestors of a common object:

```
#define WRAP(NAME, CALLEE, RET, ...) \
    using NAME##_sig = RET(__VA_ARGS__); \
    template<class T> struct NAME##_impl; \
    template<class Ret, class... Args> \
    struct NAME##_impl<Ret(Args...)> { \
        Ret operator()(Args... args) const noexcept \
        { return CALLEE(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }; \
    }; \
    using NAME = NAME##_impl<NAME##_sig>;


void examplea(char *, size_t);
void exampleb(size_t, char *);
WRAP(test_a, examplea, void, char*, size_t)
WRAP(test_b, exampleb, void, size_t, char*)

constexpr struct : test_a, test_b {} test;

void fn(char*x, size_t y) {
    test(x, y);
    test(y, x);
}
```

With thanks to Artyer for their [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76401656/2417578) illustrating these techniques for me.