# Is it possible to replace a word used within an argument to a preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Say I have a macro:

```
#define SUBST(MAGIC, ...) __VA_ARGS__  /* this won't work*/
```

And I want to call it like:

```
SUBST(int, MAGIC a = 1);

// expected output:
int a = 1;
```

Is there some set of wild indirections and expansions that I can use to force the expansion of `MAGIC` *within* the second argument with a value which depends on the call to the macro?

This comes up when the other arguments come from another layer and the `SUBST` macro is repeated many times with different values of `MAGIC`.

For example:

```
#define WRAP(function, MAGIC, stuff, ...) \
  void function(__VA_ARGS__) { stuff };
#define SUPERWRAP(function, stuff, ...) \
    WRAP(function, uint8_t, stuff##_u8, __VA_ARGS__) \
    WRAP(function, uint16_t, stuff##_u16, __VA_ARGS__)

SUPERWRAP(example, EXAMPLE_IMPL, template_t<MAGIC>, int)
```

Which cannot be solved in templates because:

```
#define WRAP(function, stuff, ...) \
  template<class MAGIC>
  int function(__VA_ARGS__) { stuff }
WRAP(example, /*...*/, template_t<MAGIC>, int)
```

doesn't allow for specialised implementaion, and and taking the type as a templatea argument in the specialisation is a partial specialisation which is also illegal.

Comment: The only way I see the `SUBST` macro evaluating to what you want is to use `#define SUBST(MAGIC_PARAM, ...)  using MAGIC = MAGIC_PARAM; __VA_ARGS__` but in many contexts this just won't work. Why exactly do you want to use a macro here anyways???

Comment: Please add an example providing a few different desired usage examples. There may be a way of doing this without using macros at all. Please add a few of these to the question. (There should be at least 2 different values for the first macro argument and several for 2 and more than one than 2 arguments total.)

Comment: The original question didn't have `template` and was a macro question. But, now it looks more like a C++ question. Should you adjust the tags to reflect this?

Comment: I do not understand the example, just `WRAP(example, uint8_t, /*...*/, template_t<uint8_t>, int)`. Or `#define WRAP2(a, b, c, ...) WRAP(a, b, c, template_t<b>, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @KamilCuk I added another layer of macro to demonstrate how `__VA_ARGS__` gets used repeatedly with different types (at much larger combinatoric scale in practice, but I think that illustrates the problem).

Comment: I did actually work out a [special-case solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76393321/2417578) for this problem, and it might be feasible to make a new kind of special case for the example I've given, but I don't want to repeat that much complexity all over again and hoped for something more generic.

Comment: @CraigEstey Initially I made the "simple example" too simple, and it was suggested I remove the C++ tag.  Then I was asked for a fuller example and I felt awkward flip-flopping by adding the tag back in.  But I guess at this stage it _is_ a C++ question.

Comment: `#define SUPERWRAP(function, stuff, ...) WRAP(function, uint8_t, stuff##_u8, template_t<uint8_t>, __VA_ARGS__)`. It's preprocessor - you have to type it out. If you want string replacement of function arguments - that's outside of C preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace a word used within an argument to a preprocessor macro?

No, it is not possible to replace a word used within an argument to a preprocessor macro.

> ```
> SUBST(int, MAGIC a = 1);
> // expected output:
> int a = 1;
> ```

That is not possible.

> Is there some set of wild indirections and expansions that I can use to force the expansion of MAGIC within the second argument with a value which depends on the call to the macro?

No.

> For example: #define WRAP(function, MAGIC, stuff, ...) \

Using C macros to generate function definition results in hard to read, maintain and debug code that no one is ever able to fix or do anything with later. Consider writing the stuff that you want line by line.

You could consider using a better preprocessor, like jinja2, m4 or php.

Comment: None of these are viable when it's somebody else's code I have to interface with.  Tens of thousands of lines of copy-paste may be explicit, but a miserable job to maintain.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment doesn't cover the true horror of the situation.  It's not just "somebody else's code", but the interface between somebody else's code, and _another_ somebody else's code.  If it was just the one somebody-else I'd just do it their way and move on.

Comment: My point is, C macros are great, but become unmaintainable. Consider something else for code generation. If it becomes complicated, it means it's bad.

Comment: If only I owned the build system!  I have a hybrid preprocessor/template solution but I find it revolting.  I've been trying to minimise the preprocessor and make something more robust with templates, but templates still need too much help from preprocessor.