# C macro to bitwise-OR together a variable number of arguments (lightweight solution without P99)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need a macro that bitwise-ORs together its (variable number of) arguments:

```
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4));
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4, 8, 16));
}
```

This should print:

```
7
31
```

I have a solution using [P99](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/p99/p99-html/):

```
#include "p99/p99_for.h"

#define P00_IDT(NAME, X, I) X
 
#define BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(...) P99_FOR(A, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_BOR, P00_IDT, __VA_ARGS__)
```

However, this being the only use of P99 in my codebase, I find it a bit heavyweight to import all of P99. How can I realize this with a self-contained set of macros?

Comment: Perhaps copy onöly the macros you needs from this "P99" library into your own code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's a possibility, but I'm afraid it might require copying say hundreds of lines of code as the library is general. I suspect this can be solved with say 10 or 20 lines of code at most.

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler to just do the bitwise OR.

Comment: Why do you need this? Is it to handle some externally generated source of comma separated values or something?

Comment: But isn't it silly to do complex pre-compilation computations with C macros? They were not designed for such a task. Might as well run a script and generate an input header as needed.

Comment: @IanAbbott I need to interface with an external piece of hardware which receives arguments as bits in a bitfield. I already have `#define`s for the different bits of the bitfield, now I want a way to write my code as `HW_CMD(arg1, arg2, arg3)` rather than `HW_CMD(arg1 | arg2 | arg3)`, as I believe that a function-call-like syntax would be easier/more natural to read than bitwise ORs.

Comment: If you do use P99, it already has a `P99_BORS(...)` macro.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with 2 macros:

```
#define A(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,\
 c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,\
 f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,g0,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,...)\
 a0|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|b0|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|b6|b7|c0|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|\
 d0|d1|d2|d3|d4|d5|d6|d7|e0|e1|e2|e3|e4|e5|e6|e7|f0|f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7|\
 g0|g1|g2|g3|g4|g5|g6|g7|h0|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|h7

#define B(...) A(__VA_ARGS__,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",B(1,2,4,8));
    printf("%d\n",B(1,2,4,8,16));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763277/11993121).

For example with up to 5 arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOR2(a,b) ((a) | (b))
#define BOR3(a,b,c) (BOR2(a,b) | (c))
#define BOR4(a,b,c,d) (BOR3(a,b,c) | (d))
#define BOR5(a,b,c,d,e) (BOR4(a,b,c,d) | (e))

#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME
#define BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, BOR5, BOR4, BOR3, BOR2)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4));
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4, 8, 16));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent start. However I'm working with large bitfields (with 64-bit variables) so potentially I'd need as many as 64 arguments -- quite unlikely I'd use all of them, but certainly more than 5. I think I've seen somewhere a trick so you can build only a logarithmic amount of the `BOR2`, `BOR3`, etc. macros?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using a compound literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(...)               \
    bitwise_or_multiple_args(                       \
        (int []){__VA_ARGS__},                      \
        sizeof((int []){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) \
    )

static int bitwise_or_multiple_args(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int rc = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rc |= arr[i];
    }
    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4));
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4, 8, 16));
    return 0;
}
```

or combined with a variadic function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(...)                   \
    bitwise_or_multiple_args(                           \
        sizeof((int []){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int),    \
        __VA_ARGS__                                     \
    )

static int bitwise_or_multiple_args(size_t n, ...)
{
    int rc = 0;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rc |= va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4));
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4, 8, 16));
    return 0;
}
```

Under gcc/clang you can avoid the auxiliar function with a statement expression:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(...) __extension__ \
({                                                  \
    int arr[] = {__VA_ARGS__};                      \
    size_t n = sizeof arr / sizeof(arr[0]);         \
    int rc = 0;                                     \
                                                    \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)                  \
    {                                               \
        rc |= arr[i];                               \
    }                                               \
    rc;                                             \
})

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4));
    printf("%d\n", BITWISE_OR_MULTIPLE_ARGS(1, 2, 4, 8, 16));
    return 0;
}
```