# Concatenation of tokens in variadic macros

Tags: c, macros, variadic

In C, is it possible to concatenate each of the variable arguments in a a variadic macro?

Example:

```
MY_MACRO(A, B, C) // will yield HDR_A, HDR_B, HDR_C
MY_MACRO(X, Y)    // will yield HDR_X, HDR_Y
```

The normal `##` operator has special meaning for variadic macros (avoiding the comma for empty argument list). And concatenation when used with `__VA_ARGS__` takes place with the first token only.

Example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(...) HDR_ ## __VA_ARGS__

MY_MACRO(X, Y)    // yields HDR_X, Y
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1872506/832273 this will probably help

Answer (score 6):

First, the comma rule you are mentioning is a gcc extension, standard C doesn't have it and most probably will never have it since the feature can be achieved by different means.

What you are looking for is meta programming with macros, which is possible, but you'd need some tricks to achieve that. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for.html) provides you with tools for that:

```
#define MY_PREFIX(NAME, X, I) P99_PASTE2(NAME, X)
#define MY_MACRO(...) P99_FOR(HDR_, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_SEQ, MY_PREFIX, __VA_ARGS__)
```

- Here `MY_PREFIX` describes what has to be done with the individual
  items.
- `P00_SEQ` declares how the items should be separated
- `P99_NARGS` just counts the number of arguments