# I'm trying to nest boost's "map_list_of" in C++03, but apparently construction is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
using boost::assign::map_list_of;

const std::map<int, std::map<int, char> > test = map_list_of
    (100, map_list_of
        (1, 'a')
        (2, 'b')
    )
    (101, map_list_of
        (1, 'c')
        (2, 'd')
    )
;

int main()
{
    std::cout << test.find(101)->second.find(2)->second << "\n";
}
```

I wanted the result to be a program that, when executed, outputs `d`.

Instead, [I get this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c367e5fa74a61420):

```
$ clang++ -std=c++03 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp

In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_pair.h:119:22: error: call to constructor of 'std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >' is ambiguous
        : first(__p.first), second(__p.second) { }
                            ^      ~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1843:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > >::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > >' requested here
          _M_insert_unique_(end(), *__first);
                                   ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_map.h:255:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > > >::_M_insert_unique<std::_Deque_iterator<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > >, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > &, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > *> >' requested here
        { _M_t._M_insert_unique(__first, __last); }
               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/assign/list_of.hpp:163:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::map<int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > > >::map<std::_Deque_iterator<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > >, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > &, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > *> >' requested here
            return Container( begin(), end() );
                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/assign/list_of.hpp:142:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::assign_detail::converter<boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > >, std::_Deque_iterator<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > >, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > &, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > *> >::convert<std::map<int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > > > >' requested here
            return convert<Container>( c, tag_type() );
                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/assign/list_of.hpp:436:49: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::assign_detail::converter<boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > >, std::_Deque_iterator<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > >, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > &, std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > *> >::convert_to_container<std::map<int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > > > >' requested here
            return this-> BOOST_NESTED_TEMPLATE convert_to_container<Container>();
                                                ^
main.cpp:7:50: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> > > >::operator map<std::map<int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > > > > > >' requested here
const std::map<int, std::map<int, char> > test = map_list_of
                                                 ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_map.h:171:7: note: candidate constructor
      map(const _Compare& __comp,
      ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_map.h:182:7: note: candidate constructor
      map(const map& __x)
      ^
1 error generated.
```

*(similar results under GCC)*

How can I resolve this?

I get a similar error even if I use `std::map<int, char>(map_list_of(...))` instead of `map_list_of(...)` for those inner maps.

Comment: It does work with an "implicit cast" instead of a function-style cast, though. `template<typename T> T implicit_cast(T t) { return t; }` But that kind of defeats the purpose of `map_list_of`. (The allocator and comparator constructors of `map` are `explicit`.)

Comment: @dyp: Huh, [nice](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbcb1865c54d5f7b)! That's the answer. It doesn't defeat the purpose at all, because I still get my `const` map with "inline" initialiser.

Comment: @dyp Why does implicit cast work?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because it prevents `map`'s `explicit` constructors from being candidates. A single constructor remains, as it seems.

Comment: @dyp: That'd make a cracking answer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It might be possible to restrict (your own version of) `map_list_of` to convert only to actual Container types. The current version (`generic_list`) seems to have no SFINAE-restrictions at all: `template< class Container > operator Container() const`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A better solution instead of the implicit cast is to use one of the member functions like `convert_to_container`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ummm... can you even restrict a conversion operator in C++03?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++03 defines two constructors for `map` that can be called with one argument [lib.map]p2:

> ```
> explicit map(const Compare& comp = Compare(),
>              const Allocator& = Allocator());
> // [...]
> map(const map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>& x);
> ```

boost's `map_list_of` creates an object of a `generic_list` class template instantiation, from the recent SVN:

> ```
> template< class Key, class T >
> inline assign_detail::generic_list< std::pair
>     < 
>         BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME assign_detail::assign_decay<Key>::type, 
>         BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME assign_detail::assign_decay<T>::type
>     > >
> map_list_of( const Key& k, const T& t )
> ```

Where the primary `generic_list` template contains the following conversion operator:

> ```
> template< class Container >
> operator Container() const
> {
>     return this-> BOOST_NESTED_TEMPLATE convert_to_container<Container>();
> }
> ```

Both `map` constructors are viable, as this operator allows conversion to both `map` and `Compare`. As far as I know, you cannot SFINAE-constrain a conversion operator in C++03.

---

The `map` is constructed *explicitly* when inserting a new node in the *outer* map. A pair of iterators is used to iterate over the inner `generic_list` to construct the outer `map`. Dereferencing this iterator yields a `std::pair<int, boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<int, char> >`. The node (value) type of the outer map is `std::pair<int const, std::map<int, char> >`.

Therefore, the compiler tries to construct the latter type from the former. In C++03, this `pair` constructor is not SFINAE-constrained, since that's not possible in C++03. [lib.pairs]p1

> ```
> template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V> &p);
> ```

libstdc++ implements this as follows:

```
template<class _U1, class _U2>
  pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
  : first(__p.first), second(__p.second) { }
```

I'm not entirely sure if that's compliant, since [lib.pairs]p4

> **Effects:** Initializes members from the corresponding members of the argument, performing implicit conversions as needed.

(But, as I said, SFINAE on ctors cannot be implemented in C++03.)

In C++11 and 14, this also fails, but for a different reason. Here, the pair constructors are SFINAE-constrained. But the constrain requires *implicit convertibility* (`is_convertible`), while the program has UB if the target pair of types cannot be *constructed* from the sources (`is_constructible`). I've written a bit more about this issue in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407037). Interestingly, a proposed solution [N4387](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html) to the issue mentioned in that other question says:

> It should be noted here, that for the general case the
>   `std::is_constructible<T, U>::value` requirement for the non-explicit
>   constructor which is constrained on `std::is_convertible<U, T>::value`
>   is not redundant, because it is possible to create types that can be
>   copy-initialized but not direct-initialized

This is exactly the case we run into here: A `map` can be copy-initialized from a `generic_list`, since this makes the `explicit` constructor non-viable. But a `map` cannot be direct-initialized from `generic_list`, since this makes the conversion ambiguous.

As far as I can see, N4387 does not solve the problem in the OP. On the other hand, with uniform initialization, we have an alternative to `map_list_of`. And we can SFINAE-constrain conversion operators since C++11.

---

One solution is to eliminate the `explicit` constructor by only allowing implicit conversions:

```
template<typename T> T implicit_cast(T t) { return t; }

implicit_cast<InnerMap>( map_list_of(1, 'a')(2, 'b') )
```

But there's a more direct way: simply use the `convert_to_container` member function of `generic_list`'s base class `converter` (also a class template):

```
map_list_of(1, 'a')(2, 'b').convert_to_container<InnerMap>()
```

Comment: I'm not going through overload resolution here and will just assume that clang's and gcc's interpretation is correct and the call is really ambiguous.