# Iterate and write to macro variadics?

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to add some syntax sugar in my OpenGL code.
I started with

```
    GLint mapView, mapProjection, f1;
    ...
    mapView = glGetUniformLocation( program, "mapView" );
    mapProjection = glGetUniformLocation( program, "mapProjection" );
    f1 = glGetUniformLocation( program, "f1" );
```

Converting this to a macro was easy enough

```
    #define BindUniform(name) name = glGetUniformLocation( program, #name )
    ...
    BindUniform( mapView );
    BindUniform( mapProjection );
    BindUniform( f1 );
```

Now I want to convert to a variadic macro

```
    #define BindUniforms(...) ? foreach(x) x = glGetUniformLocation( program, #x) ?
    ...
    BindUniforms( mapView, mapProjection, f1 );
```

Is it possible to achieve elegantly enough? I'm hoping for a 2-3 lines solution. I saw a 30+ lines huge macro set solution that builds on recursions but that looks like an overkill. Also note that the macro is writing to the argument, unlike some examples that I tried and can only read from it.

EDIT. I did some searching before posting this question. This question [Is it possible to iterate over arguments in variadic macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros) has a few solutions, but they are either too many lines of code or don't write to arguments.
So, the idea behind my question is how to achieve it with as **little** code as possible.

Comment: Why not using a variadic template instead?

Comment: I'm not very fluent with C++ in general and templates in particular. Could you maybe post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko You have to generate a lot of boilerplate macros to iterate over comma-separated lists of arguments, as the dupe link explains. Instead of doing it yourself, I suggest using Boost.Preprocessor library. Alternatively, if you can settle for a different syntax: `BindUniforms((mapView)(mapProjection)(f1));`, you can avoid generating boilerplate code: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2c4bda0ee004a3c).

Comment: I would like to avoid that boiler-plating because I am working on a proof of concept algo and I would like to keep it as simple and minimalist as possible.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Well, it's like to swallow one toad in order to avoid swallowing many of them ;-)