# how to define a variadic macro to initalize a union?

Tags: c++, macros, unions

I want to define a lot of union like this:

```
union {
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;  // there can be many variables
} a;
```

i dont want to make code be too large

so i want to define a macro to slove this.

the ideal macro looks like:

```
#define U(real_name, ...)/
union {\
....
```

and i just need one line to define:

```
U(a, b, c, d)
```

but i dont know how to get the variadic element from `...`, can you help on this?

Comment: Why do you need `union { float a; float b; float c; } a;`? Wouldn't `struct { float a; } a;` do basically the same job?

Comment: I want assign the variable several names, so that i can reuse the struct for different data @Caleth

Comment: "i can reuse the struct for different data" Names of data members do not need to be globally unique. It sounds like you fundamentally misunderstand what a `union` is

Comment: Unions overlay their members at the same memory location. Only one single member can be active at the same point of time. `U(a, b, c, d)` is not meaningful in this respect.

Comment: @Aconcagua i just want to use it to make my code more readable, for example, union have two member cat and dog, i want the readers can know what data i am using.

Comment: Be aware that type punning via unions is undefined behaviour in C++ (other than in C). You might want to place a cat in there. Fine. But you need to keep track of what you have placed in there by *other* means. A better/safer alternative is [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: If you are talking about cats and dogs, have you considered a polymorphic approach, dropping the union at all? `class Animal {}; class Cat : public Animal {}; class Dog : public Animal {}` – allowing to assign both cats and dogs to `Animal*` pointers (or references where better suited).

Comment: Related to [is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros)

Comment: OK, right from the start: What do you *actually* want to achieve? It looks to me more and more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define SIZEOF_VA_ARGS(...) SIZEOF_VA_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define SIZEOF_VA_ARGS_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, N, ...) N

#define U_1(type, memb)      type memb
#define U_2(type, memb, ...) type memb; U_1(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define U_3(type, memb, ...) type memb; U_2(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define U_4(type, memb, ...) type memb; U_3(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define U_5(type, memb, ...) type memb; U_4(type, __VA_ARGS__)

#define CONCAT(a, b)  a##b
#define U_(N, type, ...) CONCAT(U_, N)(type, __VA_ARGS__)

#define U(...) \
    union { U_(SIZEOF_VA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), float, __VA_ARGS__); }
```

```
U(a, b, c, d) foo;
// or
using mytype = U(a, b, c, d);
mytype foo;
```

Note that the above code only supports a maximum of five members, so if you want to use more than five members, you will need to define `U_6`, `U_7`, ..., and insert numbers to the definition of `SIZEOF_VA_ARGS`/`SIZEOF_VA_ARGS_`.