# How to concatenate/join __VA_ARGS__ with delimiters/separators?

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

I would like to expand a variadic macro to another macro that takes a single argument, which is formed by joining the variadic arguments with a delimiter/separator (e.g. "_"). Something like this:

```cpp
#define FOO(...)

FOO(a, b, c, d);
```

which expands into

```cpp
#define BAR(X)

BAR(a_b_c_d);
```

I know there is `__VA_ARGS__` for working with the variadic parameters, and `##` for concatenation. How do I use them together to achieve what I want (preferably using C++17 and older language features, without libraries such as Boost)?

Comment: you need to concatenate yje values of the variables, not their names. also consider using a variadic template

Comment: You might want to check [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thanks for catching this mistake! I amended my question to only about expansion to another macro.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Thanks for this suggestion. However, I'm working on a code base that's not likely to add Boost as a dependency. I amended my question to clarify this. Although, I think this is still a very good suggestion. Do you know which Boost header has the relevant macro definition, so that I can take a look at the source and learn how they did it?

Comment: Libraries like Boost.PP offer this with a lot of ugliness hidden behind the scenes. Given that PP libraries tend to be pretty dependency-free (you don't need all of Boost just for Boost.PP for example, literally zero other parts of Boost [according to this](https://pdimov.github.io/boostdep-report/boost-1.80.0/preprocessor.html)), I'd highly recommend not subjecting yourself to recreating the ugliness if you can avoid it. Depending what your ultimate goal is, there might also be a macro-free alternative.

Comment: Why not use a variadic template instead?

Answer (score 1):

First, there are no language feature that directly tackles the question you are trying to solve. (there might be complier specific ones, but I don't know).

---

However, if you know the upper limit of the amount of argument that macro can take(preferably not too many), you can use this answer as a guide to iterate through the `__VA_ARGS__`: [Is it possible to iterate over arguments in variadic macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros)

---

On the other hand, [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) is a header only library. While it is a pretty heavy macro-only library that could bring a lot of ugliness behind the scene, it does offer simple ways to handle macros that take up to thousands of parameter.

Here's a quick one that should work for you:

```cpp
#define CAT_OP(index, state, elem) BOOST_PP_CAT(state, BOOST_PP_CAT(_, elem))
#define CAT_SEQ(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(CAT_OP, BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(seq), BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define CAT_VA_ARGS(...) CAT_SEQ(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn3aGze3x).

It treats the variadic as a [Sequence](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), then performs a left fold over the sequence with concat operation.