# Is there any solution for unrolling parameters of variadic macro in C/C++ and generating code?

Tags: c++, c

Generating code in batch by using macro in C/C++

I want to implement a variadice macro in C/C++, which could be unrolled as a piece of code. Any number of parameters could be passed into the macro, and the macro will be unrolled as the following examle:

```c
#define DECLARE_LIST(...) // definition of the macro

DECLARE_LIST(a)
/* unrollig as
void funcA() {
    declare(a);
}

void funcB() {
    load(a);
}
*/


DECLARE_LIST(a, b, c)
/* unrollig as
void funcA() {
    declare(a);
    declare(b);
    declare(c);
}

void funcB() {
    load(a);
    load(b);
    load(c);
}
*/


DECLARE_LIST(a, b, c, d, ...) // for any number of macro parameter
```

Comment: Do you want a "C" or a "C++" answer? In C++ you would NOT use macros for this at all but variadic templates

Comment: C or C++, pick one.

Comment: Related to [is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros)

Answer (score 2):

This would be the answer for C++ using variadic templates

```
#include <iostream>

void load(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}

// c++ 17
template<typename... args_t>
void load_all(args_t&&... args)
{
    // use a fold expression 
    // creates one line of code for each argument passed in
    (load(std::forward<args_t>(args)),...);
}

// c++20
void load_all_cpp20(auto&&... args)
{
    (load(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)),...);
}

int main()
{
    int a{1};
    int b{2};
    load_all(a,b,3,4,5);
    return 0;
}
```

This code will output 1,2,3,4,5 (on new lines)

Comment: Actually, I need the name of each argument to generate code, but C++ template does not support for that. so C macro is required. The 'load function' in the example is not a actual function, it is a macro like this: `#define LOAD(var)  CallTemplateFunc<decltype(name)>(#name) `

Comment: @Gapex if you have specific requirements then they should be in your question

Comment: That macro is not self constistent (you pass `var` but use `name`). But for this I would not use macros either. Why don't you just write out the single line call where it is needed. It avoids having to look back and forth between your macros. Being explicit in the end will improve maintainability. Or in other words using macros to just safe a bit on typing I don't recommend that (for more complex things like generating unique variable names or so yes)

Comment: I mean what's wrong with `CallTemplateFunction(var)`. C++ has CTAD now so the decltype should not be needed

Comment: @Gapex: you might still add MACRO layer: `#define DECLARE_LIST(...) void funcA() { declare_all(__VA_ARGS__); } funcB() { load_all(__VA_ARGS__); }`.

Comment: Could just make a single-source for both 17 & 20 using the `__cplusplus` macros (c++17 `== 201703L` and c++20 `== 202002L`.  Just an easier way than having to define two separate functions. Nice answer.

Comment: @Gapex If you provide more details, better answers show up. Macro is not the goto solution in C++. An insightful redesign may eliminate the need to use macros.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a C/C++ answer (using [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro)):

```
#define DECL(x) declare(x);
#define LOAD(x) load(x);
#define DECLARE_LIST(f1,f2,z) void f1() { z(DECL) } void f2() { z(LOAD) } 


#define LIST_1(_) _(a)
DECLARE_LIST(funcA,funcB,LIST_1) 


#define LIST_2(_) _(a)_(b)_(c)
DECLARE_LIST(funcC,funcD,LIST_2)
```

I have taken out the function names as arguments, but thats not a requirement.